# R Markdown index for titles

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I have seen people that are able to create an index based on the titles that you have on your R markdown document like in this picture

[image]

If somebody could let me know how would I have to modify this code so it creates that left index table?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Juan Lozano"
date: "October 19, 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Title 1

Text Text Text Text Text

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Title 2

Text Text Text Text Text
````

Comment: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format#table_of_contents

Comment: Thanks, I found the info on the link you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @hrbrmstr 's link indicates there are many YAML customisations possible:
This is the sort of thing I usually use:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "john Smith"
date: "today ;)"
output:
  html_notebook:
    fig_caption: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_float: yes
  html_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_float: yes
    df_print: paged
bibliography: /path/to/library.bib
---
```